# updating listbox from another class in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What i'm trying to do is in the onopen function in Controller class i'm trying to run the update_listbox function in the View class which will update the listbox. This is giving me the error update_listbox() must be called with View instance as first argument. I don't fully understand what i'm doing so it would be very helpful if someone could explain to me what i'm doing wrong here and how to do it correctly.

cheers tchadwik

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkMessageBox import askokcancel

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self._master = master
        #filemenubar
        self.menu()
        #listbox
        self.listboxFrame = View(master)
        self.listboxFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        #entry widget
        self.EntryFrame = Other(master)
        self.EntryFrame.pack(fill = X)

    def menu(self):

        menubar = Menu(self._master)
        self._master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenubar = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenubar.add_command(label="Open Products File", command=self.onopen)
        fileMenubar.add_command(label="Save Products File", command=self.onsave)
        fileMenubar.add_command(label="exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenubar)

    def onopen(self):
        fname = askopenfilename()
        products.load_items(fname)
        View.update_listbox() #
        #this gives me error stating that it needs View instance as first argument
        #and adding self here only gives it the controller instance

class View(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.list = Listbox(self, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.list.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.current = None
        self.update_listbox()

    def update_listbox(self):   
        temp=products.get_keys()
        for i in temp:
            self.list.insert(END, str(products.get_item(i)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `View` object. For example:

```
def onopen(self):
    fname = askopenfilename()
    products.load_items(fname)

    myview = View(self._master)   # Instantiate the object
    myview.update_listbox()       # Now call update_listbox()
```

This is because the memory for the member variables (for example: `self.list`) is not allocated until the object is instantiated. Or another way to put it is that `self.list` is not created until `View.__init__()` is called, which happens when you create a `View` object from the `View` class definition.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, that works and i'm gaining a little bit more of an understanding of our it works. But now i've noticed my update_listbox fuction isn't working, it's not updating the listbox. Is there something obvious i've done wrong with that?